# What is the difference between DownloadText() and DownloadTextAsync()?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

In my code, I am fetching a reference of a blob in a container and I am calling `DownloadText()` method on it but I get an error
 `no accessible extension method 'DownloadText' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudBlockBlob' could be found`

As one of the potential fixes, visual studio tells me to use `DownloadTextAsync()` method. What is the difference between the two methods?

I am getting my storage account using `new CloudStorageAccount` and then getting the BlobClient using `storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()`. Then getting the reference to container using `GetContainerReference()` on the client and to BlockBlob using `GetBlockBlobReference()` on the container reference, I am then calling `blockBlob.DownloadText()` which is showing me the error `'CloudBlockBlob' does not contain a definition for 'DownloadText' and no accessible extension method 'DownloadText' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudBlockBlob' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and shows me to use `DownloadTextAsync()` as a potential fix.

Comment: One uses the async/await pattern (you'll have to await it), the other doesn't.

Comment: Do they both return the blob content in string?

Comment: Well, I'd expect `DownloadTextAsync` to return a `Task<string>`, which you'll get a `string` from when you `await` it.

Comment: Yes they do (sort of), but your problem has nothing to do with the Async suffix or not, and as such there is not enough information here to answer your question satisfyingly, please paste your actual code and or any other relevant information

Comment: @TheGeneral edited to tell what I am doing.

Comment: Most likely you're using .Net Core version of Storage SDK. Please note that .Net Core version of SDK does not have sync methods. It only has async methods.

Comment: How can I use sync methods then? Or is it better to use downloadasync?

Comment: @kartikeykant18, If you'd like to use  sync method DownloadText() in .net core, you can use the new azure storage nuget package Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.

Comment: @kartikeykant18, if the answer helps, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .net core project, if you're using [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) nuget package, there is only async method like `DownloadTextAsync`, no sync method like `DownloadText`.

But the new package [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/) does support sync and async method like `DownloadTextAsync` and `DownloadText`.

It depends on you to choose sync or async method.

If the file is very large, and it will take a long time to download it, and you have some other things to do during download, you can choose async method.

Sample async code like below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //your other code
        CloudBlockBlob myblob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("mytemp.txt");

        Console.WriteLine("in main thread: start download 111");

        //assume the download would take 10 minutes. 
        Task<string> s = myblob.DownloadTextAsync();            

        //The message will print out immediately even if the download is in progress.
        Console.WriteLine("in main thread 222!");

        //use this code to check if the download complete or not
        while (!s.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not completed");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("the string length in MB: "+s.Result.Length/1024/1024);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }    


}
```

When run the above code, you can see that the message `in main thread 222!` is printed out immediately, even if the download is in progress. And it means that you can do others thing(some other operation) when the download is in progress. They do not block each other.

And if you're using sync method, like code below:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("xxxx");

            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("f22");
            CloudBlockBlob myblob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("mytemp.txt");

            Console.WriteLine("in main thread: start download 111");

            string s = myblob.DownloadText();            

            //if the download takes 10 minutes, then the following message will be printed out after 10 minutes.
            Console.WriteLine("in main thread 222!");  

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

if the file is large, and would take 10 minutes to complete downloading. When run the code, the message `in main thread 222!` will be blocked 10 minites(after the downloading completes), then print out.